# Taking values from an array of text boxes, converting them into integers, and storing them into an array

Tags: c#

I'm making a 4-dimensional Sudoku program.
There is a 3x3 grid of 3x3 squares, each square in that 3x3 square containing a 3x3 grid of TextBoxes, so the user can enter numbers just like writing in boxes on paper. There are buttons associated to each grid of the 3x3 (so 9 buttons) that, when clicked, checks if the 3x3 grid of TextBoxes it is associated with is correct. When pressed, the button creates an array of TextBoxes `TextBox[] z_w`, where z_w are it's z and w coordinates (e.g.: one_one, two_one, three_two, etc.). A function is then called:

```
public string check_section(TextBox[] tbxnames)
    {
        int[] answers = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            foreach (TextBox tbx in tbxnames)
            {
                answers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

When the program is run the GUI appears and I am able to enter the numbers. I enter the numbers into the appropriate squares and then click the button to check it. A "FormatException was unhandled" error occurs on the line
`answers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);`. It states: "Input string was not in a correct format". How can I fix this?

I also tried this format:

```
public string check_section(TextBox[] tbxnames)
    {
        int[] answers = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            answers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(tbxnames[i].Text);
        }
    }
```

The same error occurs.

Comment: You're going to want to validate your input for actual integers. `Int.TryParse()` is what you need.

Comment: You should really investigate what's in tbxnames[i].Text. If what's in there isn't an int then it will throw that error.

Comment: `int result; answers[i] = Int32.TryParse(tbxnames[i].Text, out result) ? result : 0;`

Comment: If you don't want to validate,  simply use Int.Parse

Comment: Most likely the problem is ocurring when the textbox doesnt have a text yet. Try something like

     answers[i] = (tbxnames[i].Text == "") ?(Convert.ToInt32(tbxnames[i].Text)) : 0;

in this case the array int will take a value of 0 if the text is empty.

Comment: See my solution on following webpage for buttons.  You can replace the buttons with textboxes.  The code shown how you can create a two dimensional array of a controls (button, textbox, ...) List<List<TextBox>>